# How to use name function to define offset formula?

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I need to create a name using the name manager tool in Excel to create an offset function for the range of a chart.

I have 100 plus Excel files. I created the loop that iterates through them.

I don't know how to create a name and manipulate the chart range.

Pseudo code.

```
While file available in folder
Open file
Go to tab 1
Go to table 1 
open name manager 
Create new name that counts number of rows in column a dynamically 
Create new name that counts number of rows in column b dynamically 
Set the two names as ranges for existing chart called chart 1 
Go to next file
```

Basically I want to do the same as this video. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1VnITD0rU1A

**Edit:**
As suggested I recorded the macro:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 3")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -0.8822834646
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 275.2940944882
Range("O18").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TimeStamp", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('KPI 2'!R6C16,,,COUNT('KPI 2'!C16),1)"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("TimeStamp").Comment = ""
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="RunTime", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('KPI 2'!R6C17,,,COUNT('KPI 2'!C17),1)"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("RunTime").Comment = ""
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="AverageRunTime", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=OFFSET('KPI 2'!R6C18,,,COUNT('KPI 2'!C18),1)"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("AverageRunTime").Comment = ""
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=8
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 5").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=='31-G-1A.xlsm'!TimeStamp"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=='31-G-1A.xlsm'!RunTime"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=='31-G-1A.xlsm'!TimeStamp"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=='31-G-1A.xlsm'!AverageRunTime"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=30
```

The names formula works but I get an error when trying to set the x and y values for the chart. (The file is called "31-G-1A.xlsm".)

Comment: Just tried it but getting error when trying to update chart

Answer (score 0):

When you record a macro it will add the name to the ActiveWorkbook.Names using the R1C1 notation"

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Example1", RefersToR1C1:="=OFFSET(Sheet1!R1C1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!C1),COUNTA(Sheet1!R1))"`

But you can also use RefersTo to add the name using the xlA1 notation:

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Example2", RefersTo:="=OFFSET(A1,1,0,COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))"`

Comment: Hey I tried recording it but I'm getting error when trying to use the name for x and y values. Please see the updated code.

Comment: The names scope is Workbook not Worksheet.  Try removing the `Worksheet reference `'31-G-1A.xlsm'!` . ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=='31-G-1A.xlsm'!TimeStamp"` to `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "==TimeStamp"`

Comment: Hey I changed to ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "==TimeStamp" but I'm getting error: Application defined or object-defined error

Comment: I don't use Charts much and won't be able to help you without a test stub.  You should ask a new question "How do I modify a Chart to use Named Ranges".